# Q&A Series Ideas

Tags: discussion

We had a discussion in the [Pin 13 chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/pin-13) after [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/548/i-cant-create-an-arduino-library) was posted about [starting a Q&A series](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14061889#14061889).

This question is asking a very broad question that can't (and shouldn't) be covered in one answer. AsheeshR suggested the following:

> For the library case, we could broadly cover:
>
> - How do i create the files? (done)
> - How do convert a sketch into a C library?
> - How do I convert a sketch into a C++ library?
> - How do I package a library and share it with others?
>
> The second question could further be broken down to:
>
> - How do variables interact amongst a `.cpp` and `.h` file?
> - How do function definitions in a `.cpp` and `.h` file work?
> - How do I hide local functions in my `.cpp` file?
>
> etc.

<sub>[chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14061931#14061931)</sub>

How interested would you guys be in doing a series like this?

What are some other ideas for a Q&A series?

Comment: **Don't do things covered in many tutorials.** Try to stay away from resistors or LEDs; those are *everywhere* on the web. If you want to go into a rotary encoder or a LCD display, go ahead. Try not to duplicate basic content.

Comment: Yes, [I agree](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14061889#14061889) [entirely](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/a/91/65) with @AnnonomusPerson . We should do these in cases where the available tutorials are poor, and we have some value to add (i.e. write a better guide, or maybe fill in gaps in existing tutorials).

Comment: The second question seems clearly outside the scope of arduino.SE since it is purely related to C++. The first question is more related to Arduino (IDE in particular), although bullets 2 and 3 would be more about program design (and OOO-design for bullet 3)